# Want to create folder in Django...the user wants to create subfolders

Tags: python, django, directory, subdirectory

`In my Django Application....I want to create an directory in that directory I want to create an subdirectory in that particular subdirectory I want to create another subdirectory like that the user how long wants like that they want to create an directory

Example Code in Django`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

In your Django application, you can use the os module of Python to create directories and subdirectories. Here's an example of how you can achieve this:

```
import os

def create_directory(directory_path):
    os.makedirs(directory_path, exist_ok=True)

def create_subdirectory(directory_path, subdirectory_name):
    subdirectory_path = os.path.join(directory_path, subdirectory_name)
    create_directory(subdirectory_path)

# Example usage
directory_path = '/path/to/main_directory'
create_directory(directory_path)

subdirectory_name = 'subdirectory1'
create_subdirectory(directory_path, subdirectory_name)

subsubdirectory_name = 'subdirectory2'
create_subdirectory(os.path.join(directory_path, subdirectory_name), subsubdirectory_name)
```

In this example, the create_directory function is used to create a directory at the specified directory_path. The create_subdirectory function creates a subdirectory inside the given directory_path with the provided subdirectory_name. It uses os.path.join to construct the path to the subdirectory.

You can call the create_subdirectory function as many times as needed to create multiple levels of subdirectories.